# Some of data comes null in java spring and react js

Tags: javascript, java, spring, mongodb, reactjs

I want to save all data by using react.js and Java Spring. I sent data with REST, but one of data class comes null to collections in MongoDB. I controlled whether or not all data types are equal. I cannot see and solve my errors. I share both Spring data type definitions and react.js definitions.

**BildirimGrubu comes null**

*Java Spring:*

```
package tr.com.innova.watcher;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.Data;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * Created by SBK on 03.09.2016.
 */
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class BildirimGrubu {
    String emailMetni;
    String smsMetni;
    List<Alici> alici;
    enum EmailEkTipi{
       HICBIRI, EXCEL, PDF
    };
    EmailEkTipi ekTip;
    enum BildirimYontemi{
        EMAIL, SMS, HEPSI, HICBIRI
    };
    BildirimYontemi bildirimYont;
    int mesajSayisi;
    int mesajKarakter;
}
```

*React.js:*

```
import * as React from "react";


export enum EmailEkTipi{
    HICBIRI, EXCEL, PDF
}
export enum BildirimYontemi {
    EMAIL, SMS, HEPSI, HICBIRI
}
export enum TetikleyiciTipi{
    CRON, SIMPLE
}
export class Alici {
    label:string;
    value:string;

    constructor(name:string,
                val:string) {
        this.label = name;
        this.value = val;

    }
}
export class BildirimGrubu {
    emailMetni:string;
    smsMetni:string;
    alici:Array<Alici>;
    ekTip:EmailEkTipi;
    bildirimYont:BildirimYontemi;
    mesajSayisi:number;
    mesajKarakter:number;

    constructor(emailMetni:string, smsMetni:string, alici:Array<Alici>, ekTip:EmailEkTipi, bildirimYont:BildirimYontemi, mesajSayisi:number,mesajKarakter:number) {
        this.emailMetni = emailMetni;
        this.smsMetni = smsMetni;
        this.alici = alici;
        this.ekTip = ekTip;
        this.bildirimYont = bildirimYont;
        this.mesajSayisi = mesajSayisi;
        this.mesajKarakter = mesajKarakter;
    }
}

export class Tetikleyici {
    tetikleyiciAdi:string;
    aciklama:string;
    tetikleyiciIcerik:TetikleyiciTipi;
    durum:boolean;
    bildirimGrubu:BildirimGrubu;
    tip:TetikleyiciTipi;
    bildirimEkle:boolean;

    constructor(tetikleyiciAdi:string, aciklama:string, tetikleyiciIcerik:TetikleyiciTipi, durum:boolean, bildirimGrubu:BildirimGrubu, tip:TetikleyiciTipi, bildirimEkle:boolean) {
        this.tetikleyiciAdi = tetikleyiciAdi;
        this.aciklama = aciklama;
        this.tetikleyiciIcerik = tetikleyiciIcerik;
        this.durum = durum;
        this.bildirimGrubu = bildirimGrubu;
        this.tip = tip;
        this.bildirimEkle = bildirimEkle;
    }
}
export class Sorgu {
    _id:string;
    userName:string;
    anaSorgu:string;
    aciklama:string;
    altSorguList:Array<string>;
    tetikleyici:Tetikleyici;
    sName:string;

    constructor(id:string, username:string, anaSorgu:string, aciklama:string, altSorguList:Array<string>, tetikleyici:Tetikleyici, sName:string) {
        this._id = id;
        this.userName = username;
        this.anaSorgu = anaSorgu;
        this.aciklama = aciklama;
        this.altSorguList = altSorguList;
        this.tetikleyici = tetikleyici;
        this.sName=sName;
    }
}
```

*Data to send DB with REST:*

```
[new Sorgu("1","Hi","select","select sorgusu",["hi","hoy"],new Tetikleyici("tetikle", "hello", TetikleyiciTipi.CRON, true, new BildirimGrubu("a", "a", [["ali","bak"]], EmailEkTipi.EXCEL, BildirimYontemi.HEPSI, 1, 1), TetikleyiciTipi.CRON, true),"sorgu_8")]
```

I hope to transferred you my problems. Thank you for helps.

Comment: How do you use enum in your javascript ? Does this code run without errors ? Does it run on browser ?

Comment: There is no error. I use enum type both of them (java spring and react.js). Is it a problem for me? I use Chrome as web browser. @FurkanO

Comment: Enum is not available in Javascript

Comment: I know enum is available in TypeScript (ES6). I used ES6 to code React.js @FurkanO

Comment: Also, there is no error other data group. For example, I used enum in Tetikleyici class and it does not return null type. I think the problem is not related to enum. @FurkanO

Comment: Sure. You could say I am using TypeScript after my first question. For me, it is hard to read typescript code. Sorry I can't help.

Comment: I see. Btw, thanks. @FurkanO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While again created classes, I realized that I forgot to add public. Therefore, java cannot access the objects of the class. Don't forget public. :)

Even so, thank you!